# login loop - ubuntu 16.04 - nvidia

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm

I've tried what's recommended in several of the questions that deal with the "login loop" with none of the solutions working. 
BTW, I have an nvidia GPU: GTX 1080.

Concretelly I've tried with no results:

- Copying .Xauthority and .ICEauthority, or changing ownership to the user.
- Removing and re-instlalling lightdm
- purging nvidia drivers: 
  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`, `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`,
  `sudo service lightdm restart` and reboot

Following this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) advice I include the output of .xsession-errors.

```
$ cat ~/.xsession-errors
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3270) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (3262) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (3118) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (3181) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (3320) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (3333) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (3334) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (3321) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (3359) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (3325) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 pre-start process (3263) terminated with status 143
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (3328) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (3281) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (3332) killed by TERM signal
```

Comment: What graphics card are you using? If it is an nVidia card try pressing Crtl + Alt + F2, logging in, and then running "sudo apt-get purge nvidia.*" and rebooting.

Comment: I have a GTX 1080 and have installed cuda, etc.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment. How did you install a nvidia driver on ubuntu 16.04? I also have a GTX 1080 (XPS 15 9560). I get into infinite login loop after installing nvidia driver using ppa. None of 384, 390, 396 worked for me. I can get out of the login loop by uninstalling Nvidia: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-* sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: That didn't work for me. But who knows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was basically nvidia drivers screwing up the system so badly that the nvidia re-install didn't work as expected.

They say to diagnose this is by running in the terminal: `nvidia-smi` which returned.
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

The solution was basically a full re-install of the OS. So downloading ubuntu 16.04 in a USB drive, re-installing ubuntu.

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

this is the driver for GTX 1080 from: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=debnetwork

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cuda
```

then reboot and everything works, for now. 
Thanks nvidia for your trashy software!

Here is the discussion of the topic from [nvidia-forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1000340/cuda-setup-and-installation/-quot-nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldn-t-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-quot-ubuntu-16-04/4) with some extra details.

Answer (score 1):

As you are are using an nVidia GTX card try pressing Crtl + Alt + F2, logging in, and then running

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia.*

And then rebooting.

If you are using Bumblebee to switch between GPU cards the command should be

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia.* bumblebee

Edit: I did get nVidia working with a nVidia driver on 16.04. The only driver I managed to get to work is the nvidia-364, from ubuntu graphics ppa. Here is what I did:

First get purge all existing nVidia drivers with

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

and the reboot the system.

Then install nvidia-364 from the repository ubuntu graphics ppa

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-364

Then reboot.

If that doesn't work I would try purging Cuda too.

Comment: what is bunblebee supposed to do? I've tried purging nvidia and re-installing with no sucess already. But after running nvidia-smi I get `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Comment: Bumblebee is used to utilise the nVidia Optimus system on Ubuntu laptops. I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that you don't use Bumblebee

Comment: Knock it off, guys.  We don't need useless bickering here.