# Ubuntu 16.04 Login Loop Nvidia GTX1080ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I am using ubunbtu 16.04 with an nvidia 1080 GTX ti GPU and I have become stuck in a "login-loop". I have tried the classic:
`chown user:user .Xauthority`

`chmod 666 .Xauthority`

`chmod a+wt /temp`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Interestingly, when I run `nvidia-smi` I get the expected output and I can see the driver version is: 396.24.

Is this a driver issue? Should I run follow [login loop - ubuntu 16.04 - nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015666/login-loop-ubuntu-16-04-nvidia)?

Comment: Hi and welcome. 16.04 is out of standard support in a few weeks, That means no questions here on that version can be answered and no updates of any kind will be available for it. Time to upgrade. This may also solve your problem.

Comment: And if you upgrade, a clean install is most times the best way to go

Comment: Thanks so much for the heads-up @David! Indeed, sounds like it might be time for an upgrade. But with the login-loop, it still means that  I cannot log in and run software update. How can I get around this?

Comment: The easiest would be a fresh install of 18.04 or 20.04, any upgrade may carry the problem over to the new version.